# convert quarter string to specific dates

Tags: conversion

I have a column with multiple choice showing different Fiscal Year Quarters:

- FY24 Q01
- FY24 Q02
- FY24 Q03
- FY24 Q04

This column is for the user to be friendly.

**How do I convert this column to specific dates?**

**Example**:

- FY24 Q01= 5/29/23
- FY24 Q02= 8/29/2023
- FY24 Q03= 11/28/2023
- FY24 Q04= 2/27/2024